# How do I use SetText to access strings that are in an array (in xml)? Android

Tags: android, arrays, settext

I have a string array defined in xml:

```
<string-array name="question_array">                        
    <item> q1 "First string"</item>  
    <item> q2 "Second string "</item>  
</string-array>
```

and want to use SetText to access and display these strings.  None of these variations work:

```
setText(R.array.question_array[counter]);
setText(R.string.question_array[counter]);
setText(R.array.question_array);
setText(R.string.question_array);
```

What is the proper syntax for doing this?

Answer (score 2):

```
            Resources r = getResources();
    Duration = r.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);//duration is array i created in my code
```

create your own array and use it in your code